# get all results with Dismax, like q=*:*?

Tags: lucene, solr

Is not possible to do this like `q=*:*` with DisMax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first thanks for you answers.
Actually i found the solution that fit my need and it's  :

```
 < str name="q.alt">*:*< /str>
```

now i can list all the results .

;)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get all results with dismax using the `*:*` query.

To get the count of documents with this query, you have to use the standard query handler. You can switch to it by adding `qt=standard` in your query. Note that 'standard' is the default name, so check in your solrconfig.xml if it is the name you are really using.

Comment: I tried it out, and you are right, *:* doesn't seem to play nice with Dismax.   HOwever, instead of doing qt=standard, and therefore pointing to a completely different requestHandler, instead do defType=lucene, and reuse the same requestHandler, just overtide the use of dismax.